# Add forbidden words to TexStudio / Latex

Tags: latex, spell-checking, pdflatex

I have some words in my language (German) that seem to be valid according to TexStudios spellchecker.
However they must not be used for my thesis (and globally for me at least).
Is it possible to add words to a list, that trigger a (optimally huge) sign "DO NOT USE THIS!" or even prevent compilation in Latex when such words are used?

I'm looking for something like a negative dictionary.
I've seen files like "badwords" or "stopwords" but don't know when/how they are used. I can freely use them although "check for bad words" is on.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has the problem: Badword files are named after the main language. For me it happened that I have "de_DE_frami" as the dictionary set. Hence it did not use the "de_DE.badwords".

For a good highlighting: One can change the appearance in the options dialog (syntaxhighlighting->badwords) and make it e.g. background red, size 200%

I'd still would like to have a "bad" words and a "impossible" words distinction as you can sometimes not avoid "bad" words or they are not bad in all contexts.